# Android LocationManager requestLocationUpdates changed?

Tags: android, gps, android-4.4-kitkat, locationmanager

My app is working in Ice Cream Sandwich perfectly well, but now I tried it on KitKat and faced some problems.

The app is kind of server I'm running in my old phone and it provides location when requested. In ICS when the location is requested the GPS icon starts blinking and soon the app receives location update and sends it forward. But now with KitKat the GPS icon does not start blinking when location is requested. The app gives 60s time for finding the GPS location, but usually the GPS isn't even activated during this time. Still now and then the GPS suddenly activates itself (during the 60s) and the location is provided to my app.

Why the GPS doesn't get activated even my app requests location? **As said, my app works with ICS without problems.** And I do have required permissions set in my manifest.

public variables:

```
public static LocationManager mlocManager = null;
public static LocationListener mlocListener_fast = null;
```

onCreate:

```
mlocListener_fast = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Handling user requested command (location request)

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener_fast);
```

What should I do differently to get the GPS location instantly without waiting for sudden location updates/GPS activation, probably triggered by Android or some other app?? Unfortunately I don't have any other Android device I could try this.

EDIT:

It seems that if the app does not request location at startup, then the location request works every time when requested time after time. But if the location was requested (and received) on startup, then the location request does not work anymore. What can cause that? I use exactly the same line (the same location mgr and the same location listener) for location request on startup and later if requested.

Even if the location listener used in startup is different than the one used later, the location request does not work anymore. Tried even initialize the location mngr again just before requesting the location again and it did not help. What's with this??

EDIT2:

It just seems that with KitKat it's not possible to request multiple location requests. I used to have several location listeners for different purposes. For example one for updating location once per hour and another for getting location instantly (user requested update). Now it seems that if I have the 1/60min location listener running as normal, then KitKat location manager fails to handle the instant location requests. Have anyone faced this issue? Would be good to know which Android versions have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround for this issue is to use only one LocationManager and one LocationListener. If your app has needs for different kind of simultaneous location requests (with different parameters), then you need to implement a "location request handler" which decides which parameters should be used for the location request i.e. which parameters have the tightest requirements for location.

Here is a simple example code that explains the idea of "location request handler":

```
class LR {

    long lock_min_time; // defined in set_lock_lr before using
    float lock_min_dist;
    boolean lock_active = false;

    long idle_min_time = 3600000; // 1 per hour
    float idle_min_dist = 200;
    boolean idle_active = true;

    long fast_min_time = 0;
    float fast_min_dist = 0;
    boolean fast_active = false;

    //constructor
    public LR()
    {}

    public void set_lock_lr(long min_time, float min_dist, boolean active)
    {
        lock_active = active;
        lock_min_dist = min_dist;
        lock_min_time = min_time;
        System.out.println("LR lock set: "+min_time+", "+min_dist+", "+active);
        update_location_request();
    }

    public void set_idle_lr(boolean active)
    {
        idle_active = active;
        System.out.println("LR idle set: "+active);
        update_location_request();
    }

    public void set_fast_lr(boolean active)
    {
        fast_active = active;
        System.out.println("LR fast set: "+active);
        update_location_request();
    }

    private void update_location_request()
    {
        // Remove current location request
        mlocManager_basic.removeUpdates(mlocListener_basic);

        if(fast_active)
        {
            mlocManager_basic.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, fast_min_time, fast_min_dist, mlocListener_basic);
            System.out.println("LR: fast_active");
        }
        else if(lock_active)
        {
            mlocManager_basic.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, lock_min_time, lock_min_dist, mlocListener_basic);
            System.out.println("LR: lock_active");
        }
        else if(idle_active) // only idle updates
        {
            mlocManager_basic.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, idle_min_time, idle_min_dist, mlocListener_basic);
            System.out.println("LR: idle_active");
        }
    }
}
```